# Curse of Dimensionality: Identifying Correct Statement

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, algorithms, high-dimensional

Im trying to identify which one of these statements about the curse of dimensionality is correct:

> a) It means that the performance of the KNN classifier gets worse when the number of predictor variables $p$ is large.
>
> b) It means that the K-means clustering algorithm performs bad if the datapoints lie in a high-dimensional space.

Only one of the statements is correct.

I know that both K-means and KNN use distance calculations in their algorithms, and distances become more and more similar in higher dimensions, which leads to worse performance of the algorithms. Im a bit confused regarding what difference the points lying in a high-dimensional space, and $p$ being large makes. To me they both just mean that we are working in higher dimensions.

Comment: The question is a bit tricky. To me, statement b sounds more logical. The increasing of $p$'s dimension isn't a sufficient condition of "getting worse performance" given other facts unknown. However, high-dimensional inputs is sufficient to make an algorithm hard to perform well, if you agree with "performs bad == hard to perform well". Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Neither statement is universally true--one can come up with counterexamples for each

Comment: @user20160 I guess what they are looking for is which one of them is a result of the Curse of Dimensionality.